How to make oracle cross table query for date column
I have table department_statistics with the following structure and sample data :
DEPT_ID     SAMPLES_MORNING    TESTS_MORNING    SAMPLES_EVENING TESTS_EVENING  DATE 
  1               50              200                75             160        6/12/2024
  2               53              210                79             120        6/12/2024
  3               40              100                35             110        6/12/2024
  1               50              200                75             160        6/13/2024
  2               43              110                79             100        6/13/2024
  3               40              100                35             110        6/13/2024

I need the output of query like this :
DEPT_ID       6/12/2024                                          6/13/2024
  1      sum_samples_morning  sum_samples_evening         sum_samples_morning  sum_samples_evening    
  2      sum_samples_morning  sum_samples_evening         sum_samples_morning  sum_samples_evening
  3      sum_samples_morning  sum_samples_evening         sum_samples_morning  sum_samples_evening

how can I do that and thank you in advance

PIVOT the table:
SELECT dept_id,
       dt_2024_06_12_samples_morning,
       dt_2024_06_12_samples_evening,
       dt_2024_06_13_samples_morning,
       dt_2024_06_13_samples_evening
FROM   table_name
PIVOT (
  SUM(samples_morning) AS samples_morning,
  SUM(tests_morning  ) AS tests_morning,
  SUM(samples_evening) AS samples_evening,
  SUM(tests_evening  ) AS tests_evening
  FOR dt IN (
    DATE '2024-06-12' AS dt_2024_06_12,
    DATE '2024-06-13' AS dt_2024_06_13
  )
);

or use conditional aggregation:
SELECT dept_id,
       SUM(CASE dt WHEN DATE '2024-06-12' THEN samples_morning END)
         AS dt_2024_06_12_samples_morning,
       SUM(CASE dt WHEN DATE '2024-06-12' THEN samples_evening END)
         AS dt_2024_06_12_samples_evening,
       SUM(CASE dt WHEN DATE '2024-06-13' THEN samples_morning END)
         AS dt_2024_06_13_samples_morning,
       SUM(CASE dt WHEN DATE '2024-06-13' THEN samples_evening END)
         AS dt_2024_06_13_samples_evening
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY dept_id;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (DEPT_ID, SAMPLES_MORNING, TESTS_MORNING, SAMPLES_EVENING, TESTS_EVENING, DT) AS
SELECT 1, 50, 200, 75, 160, DATE '2024-06-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 53, 210, 79, 120, DATE '2024-06-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 40, 100, 35, 110, DATE '2024-06-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 50, 200, 75, 160, DATE '2024-06-13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 43, 110, 79, 100, DATE '2024-06-13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 40, 100, 35, 110, DATE '2024-06-13' FROM DUAL;

Both output:



DEPT_ID
DT_2024_06_12_SAMPLES_MORNING
DT_2024_06_12_SAMPLES_EVENING
DT_2024_06_13_SAMPLES_MORNING
DT_2024_06_13_SAMPLES_EVENING




1
50
75
50
75


2
53
79
43
79


3
40
35
40
35



fiddle

about the date I have date range for example where date between 2024-06-12 and 2024-06-18 it can be give each day in one column ?

@ZiadAdnan You could concatenate the morning and evening values into a single string using dt_2024_06_12_samples_morning || ' ' || dt_2024_06_12_samples_evening AS dt_2024_06_12 but you have two values so having two columns per day makes much more sense.
